# How to Reference A Binary File in a C# ClickOnce Install Application

Tags: c#, clickonce

I'm currently using C# to build an app using *WebView2*, however, I need to make it accessible for those who are currently not on *Edge*.  I decided to [use a fixed version runtime, as documented here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#details-about-the-fixed-version-runtime-distribution-mode)
I'm going to use "*EnsureCoreWebView2Async*" to specify my environment.

My question is how do I reference the binary files needed in the "*browserExecutableFolder*" parameter in "*CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync*" if I'm going to package the project using *ClickOnce*?  I won't know where the user will install the file, so I don't know what directory to reference.  Could I just reference the file based on the package directory, like below:

```
"...\\bin\\Release\\net5.0-windows\\programName.exe.Webview2\\EBWebView\\x64\\EmbeddedBrowserWebView.dll"
```

...or is there another file reference syntax I would need to use?

Sorry if this seems like a beginner's question, but I just recently started learning C#/.NET and I'm still trying to get the hang of programming altogether. :-)

Comment: Stack Overflow uses [Markdown](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/); most of your HTML decoration is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can package the binary file in the click once installer. When this gets extracted the binary file will be in the same (i recon) directory as the application installed.
Which click once installer will be used for installing the application?

Once you know where the binary file gets placed on installation and if it is in the same folder as the installed application, you can use the following code for getting to that path.

```
var exePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
```

[Documentation for above](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly?view=net-5.0)

When using it with `Path.Combine(exepath, "nameofbinaryfile");`

You can get a reference to the binary file.

Comment: I'm using the standard ClickOnce installer that comes with VS 2019.  I realize I can add the file post and reference it, but I wasn't sure how to reference the location if I didn't know where the user would install the file, however, if I could just refer to it as within the parent file on where the user installed it, I'm assuming that the path would look like "[installation directory]...\\bin\\publish\\...file.dll".

If I'm wrong, please let me know.  I've never done this before.

Comment: You would be wise to determine what behaviour the installer has. Use a virtual machine and install the click once there. If you've packed the required binary in the installer you'll know the location where it'll end up